# Specify data for Fullcalendar's eventSources

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery Fullcalendar plugin. On the same page, I have a form with checkboxes which are used to filter the event data fetched from the server. The idea is that I want to pass those form values into the `eventSources` object, so that they get transmitted to the server together with the start/end timestamps.

[The docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) have a sample `eventSources` object like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   eventSources: [
     // your event source
      {
        url: '/myfeed',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          custom_param1: 'something',
          custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
        },
      }
      // other sources...
   ]
});
```

Which I modified to:

```
   eventSources: [
   {
     // ...as above
     data: getFormAsObject(),
     // as above...
   }
```

I want the form's values to get passed into the the `data` object. In the `getFormAsObject()` function, I serialize the form and convert that to an associative array.

All that is left is to hijack the form submission. So if the "submit" button is clicked, I cancel the default POST action, and call

```
calendar.fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
```

BUT, this doesn't work, and the `getFormAsObject()` doesn't get called at all. *What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: Strangely enough, the function gets called once when the page loads (and the calendar is initialized), but not again after that.

Comment: I also tried `data: function () { return getFormAsObject(); },` which doesn't trigger it either

Comment: not easy to follow sequence of events easily here.  Start by addressing if any errors are thrown in console

Comment: not enough code here or full sequence description to really follow how app works. For example if you initialize plugin on page load...form elements haven't likely been populated yet

Comment: no everything works as described (I think!), and the plugin does work; but it's as if it ignores the `data` object. I assume I'm passing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is (it seems) that Fullcalendar only reads that `data` object once. So it reads it the first time and then not again, even if I set it to a function. I'm not certain, but I think it may be how the underlying `ajax()` call works?

So I've changed it to remove the `eventSources` and then readd new ones every time I do an update. Seems ugly, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Dynamic data parameter"
Second last option here:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  events: {
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    data: function() { // a function that returns an object
      return {
        dynamic_value: Math.random()
      };
    }
  }

});
```